# I'm getting a strange error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm trying to have my order history screen screen display the order history of a specific user. When I go to the path I have the error that is in the title. I made sure that the path is correct and that I spelled everything correctly but it's still coming back undefined. I also did console logs in the function and it's coming back with nothing which let's me know that the function isn't getting to the backend. I don't know what else to do. Below is the code for reference:

screen.js

```
import { axios } from "axios";
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/esm/Button";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet-async";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
import LoadingBox from "../components/LoadingBox";
import MessageBox from "../components/MessageBox";
import { getError } from "../utils";
import { Store } from "./Store";
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_REQUEST":
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case "FETCH_SUCCESS":
      return { ...state, orders: action.payload, loading: false };
    case "FETCH_FAIL":
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default function OrderHistoryScreen() {
  const { state } = useContext(Store);
  const { userInfo } = state;
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [{ loading, error, orders }, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    loading: true,
    error: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      dispatch({ type: "FETCH_REQUEST" });
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          `/api/orders/mine`,

          { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` } }
        );
        dispatch({ type: "FETCH_SUCCESS", payload: data });
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
          type: "FETCH_FAIL",
          payload: getError(error),
        });
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [userInfo]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Order History</title>
      </Helmet>
      <h1>Order History</h1>
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>DATE</th>
              <th>TOTAL</th>
              <th>PAID</th>
              <th>DELIVERED</th>
              <th>ACTIONS</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {orders.map((order) => {
              <tr key={order._id}>
                <td>{order._id}</td>
                <td>{order.createdAt.substring(0, 10)}</td>
                <td>{order.totalPrice.tofixed(2)}</td>
                <td>{order.isPaid ? order.paidAt.substring(0, 10) : "No"}</td>
                <td>
                  {order.isDelivered
                    ? order.deliveredAt.substring(0, 10)
                    : "No"}
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Button
                    type="button"
                    variant="light"
                    className="cusButton"
                    onClick={() => {
                      navigate(`/order/${order._id}`);
                    }}
                  >
                    Details
                  </Button>
                </td>
              </tr>;
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

orderRoutes.js

```
const orderRouter = express.Router();

orderRouter.get(
  "/mine",
  isAuth,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const orders = await Order.find({ user: req.user._id });
    if (orders) {
      console.log("these are the orders: " + orders);
      res.send(orders);
    } else {
      console.log("Order not found");
    }
  })
);

orderRouter.get(
  "/:id",
  isAuth,
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id);
    if (order) {
      res.send(order);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send({ message: "Order Not Found" });
    }
  })
);

export default orderRouter;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `axios` import statement to:

```
import axios from "axios";
```